# How can I make an array empty?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I use Ag Grid to draw a table. To fill data in rows I use this method:

```
getTable(): void {
    this.rowData = [];
    this.service.getAllUserOrders().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        for (const item of response.body) {
          this.rowData.push({
            number: item.order_number,
            status: item.status,
            service: item.deal_type,
            delivery: item.delivery_type,
            ttn: '',
            sender: item.sender_name,
            recipient: item.recipient_name,
            place: item.delivery_placing_type,
            amount: item.amount_packages,
            address1: item.sender_address,
            date1: item.sender_delivery_from.split(' ')[0],
            time11: item.sender_delivery_from.split(' ')[1],
            time12: item.sender_delivery_to.split(' ')[1],
            address2: item.recipient_address,
            date2: item.recipient_accept_from.split(' ')[0],
            time21: item.recipient_accept_from.split(' ')[1],
            time22: item.recipient_accept_to.split(' ')[1],
            author: item.userId,
            id: item.id
          });
        }
        this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
      }
    });
  }
```

It is used on grid initialization:

```
onGridReady(params: any): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.getTable();
  }
```

Also I use getTable() when I send data after rows select:

```
sendOrders(event: any): void {
    for (const item of this.selectedOrderRows) {
      console.log('ITEM:', item);
      this.service.sendOrder(item).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Order id ' + item + ' is sent');
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I want to refresh my table in such way, but the array this.rowData has the old information. I tried to log in getTable() value of this.rowData after this row:

```
this.rowData = [];
```

Also I tried slice(), but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);` after emptying the array?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to get your row data:

```
getAllRows() {
  let updatedRowData = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => updatedRowData.push(node.data));
  return updatedRowData;
}
```